# How to Make Shaka Player Compatible with react Native?

Tags: react-native, shaka

I am working on React-Native application. i want to implement shaka player in react-native.
any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [shaka-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shaka-player) npm package? You can use it within your React component and instantiate as state.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import shaka from 'shaka-player';


const Component = () => {
   const playerRef = useRef();
   const [videoPlayer, setVideoPlayer] = useState();

   useEffect(() => {
       if (!videoPlayer) {
          const newPlayer = new shaka.Player(playerRef.current);
          setVideoPlayer(newPlayer);
          // you can start using shaka-player APIs with videoPlayer
       }
   }, []);

   return (
       <video ref={playerRef} />
   );
}
```

Comment: is it work in react native mobile app IOS and Android both ? plz explain clearly !